# Write accented characters to rtf in python

Tags: python, unicode, rtf

I am trying to write to an rtf file a lot of information in French, containing accented characters. First, I tried using codecs to write to the file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import codecs

output = codecs.open("test.rtf", "w", 'utf-8')
name = unicode("Lumière", 'utf-8')

# This is just the rtf header 
# The whole point of using rtf is so that I can embed links
output.write("{\\rtf1\\ansi\\ansicpg1252\\deff0\\deflang1033{" + 
    "\\fonttbl{\\f0\\fnil\\fcharset0 Calibri;}}\\n{\\colortbl ;" + 
    "\\red0\\green0\\blue255;}\n{\\*\\generator Msftedit 5.41.21.2509;}" + 
    "\\viewkind4\\uc1\\pard\\sa200\\sl276\\slmult1\\lang9\\f0\\fs22\n\n")

output.write(name)

output.write("}")
output.close()
```

This outputs an *.rtf file that dislplays as:

LumiÃ¨re

Both in textEdit and in MS word. Opening it as a text document in a plain text editor we get:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Calibri;}}\n{\colortbl ;\red0\green0\blue255;}
{\*\generator Msftedit 5.41.21.2509;}\viewkind4\uc1\pard\sa200\sl276\slmult1\lang9\f0\fs22

Lumière}
```

Which is the gobbledeegook for the header, and the word, properly formatted. If I edit the rtf  document directly, to add the è character, the source changes to:

```
Lumi\'e8re
```

Which is extremely similar to:

```
>>> name = unicode("Lumière", 'utf-8')
>>> name
u'Lumi\xe8re'
```

Which is clearly what I need to write to the file, but swapping the 'x' for an apostrophe. If I try to write without encoding (don't use codecs to open file), I get the famous

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe8' in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

error. How to I get file.write() to stop trying to encode, I want to literally write '\xe8' not the character '\xe8' represents to the file (except I want to swap the 'x' for an apostrophe).

Comment: RTF doesn't use UTF-8; it uses UTF-16. I've duped this to another question dealing with RTF and Unicode, where my answer applies to your problem too.

Comment: Thanks! You're absolutely correct, sorry for the duplicate question.

Comment: Not a problem; your question now acts as a way sign.